# Bootstrap 4 weird behavior on small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I use Bootstrap 4 for making my website responsive. Bootstrap is a Mobile first. As I understand that's mean I should first write CSS for small screens and then add breakpoints for bigger screens. 
That's what I have:

```
 #main{
   width: 100%;
 }

 @media (min-width: 576px) { 
   #main{
     width: 90%;
   } 

 @media (min-width: 768px) { 
   #main{
     width: 80%;
   } 
 }
```

When in Chrome I open console and click "Toggle Device Toolbar" and change screen width to 350px ("responsive"), it uses css for 'min-width 768 px' (not even for 576px) and makes #main width 80%.
Why is that happening and how to solve it? Thank you!

Comment: ?? , you are not suppose to rewrite the breakpoints, they are already set in the boostrap library. You  need to use the provided class by bootsrap and it will be taking care of it .   or is it  custom class of your own ?

Comment: That's why I got confused: why Bootstrap breakpoints don't work. They actually work only when I shrink window. If I check this page using "Toggle Device Toolbar" or just upload it somewhere and check from my smartphone, breakpoints don't work

Comment: Have you set width to device-width using  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">. Check starter template https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@media screen and (min-width: [...]px)`. Otherwise your code seems good.

Comment: you heard of "mobile-first"?

Comment: What is not mobile-first about it?

Comment: wrting a MQ for a smaller size (576-767) AFTER a MQ for a larger size (768+). mobile first = small sizes first

Comment: Whoops, I should have checked my answer twice before posting. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `@media screen and (min-width: XXXpx) { ... }` instead of just `@media (min-width: XXXpx)`